# how to do unit testing for react-native applications

Tags: unit-testing, react-native

Hi this is a sample class which I want to write unit for

```
export default class testProject extends Component {

 _sum(a, b) {
      return a + b;
  } 

render() {
   return (
       <View>
            <Text>Business Finance</Text>
       </View>
          );
         }
}
```

what tools do I need to test both UI and the Bussiness logic :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day of reading documents a stright answer for the question

For UI -> Enzyme and Jest
example :->

```
    import Index from '../index.android.js';
    const expectedText = 'Business Finance';
    let wrapper=shallow(<Index />);
    expect(wrapper.find('Text').children().text()).toEqual(expectedText);
```

For Businesslogic testing ->Enzyme

```
expect(wrapper.instance()._sum(2,3)).toBe(5);
```

Comment: Jest easy to use :)  -----> expect(sum(2, 3)).toBe(5);

Comment: but running -> expect(sum(2, 3)).toBe(5); . Gives sum is undefined error , you need to export the functions and import them in test scripts, but by this way -> expect(wrapper.instance()._sum(2,3)).toBe(5);   there's no need to export the functions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this articles then you can write test :)

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html

https://blog.callstack.io/unit-testing-react-native-with-the-new-jest-i-snapshots-come-into-play-68ba19b1b9fe

https://blog.callstack.io/unit-testing-react-native-with-the-new-jest-ii-redux-snapshots-for-your-actions-and-reducers-8559f6f8050b

https://medium.com/@romarioraff/testing-react-apps-with-jest-and-chai-enzyme-for-beginners-baa5f57cec0b

https://medium.com/@dschmidt1992/jest-snapshot-testing-3ef9fa1222bb

Comment: Helped a lot Thank you @BurhanYilmaz